# Test Rapid Orientation Change

Tags: android

My app's pre-launch report is showing a crash that only occurs on orientation change and only after a LOT of rapid changes.

Is there a configurable test I can run that just attacks the app with orientation changes so I can reproduce this crash?

I tried using monkey testing but the randomness makes it near useless for this specific case.

Thanks all!

for reference, here's the crash in question:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Item at position 0 requires 4
>   spans but GridLayoutManager has only 3 spans.

I know where I'm going from a span count of 4 to 3 on orientation change so I know where the crash is happening.  I even have a fix in place.  I just need to confirm the fix, which is why I need this test

Comment: How about putting the breakpoints in android studio ? if you are doing something on changing the orientation through code

Comment: @praveenpanishetti I've tried that.  Unfortunately, it's really hard to reproduce and debug mode slows it down so much that it doesn't reproduce at all.  It only happens on roughly 1/400 orientation changes based on the report but we have 150K users.  Can't release when 1/400 of them are going to be crashing all over the place

Comment: Which recyclerview version are you using?

Comment: @MatPag androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.0.0

Comment: I think there is a bug in `GridLayoutManager` (or maybe it's not build to solve this problem). You can try to add a small delay after rotation before updating spansize

Comment: Searching at this [line](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/refs/heads/androidx-master-dev/recyclerview/recyclerview/src/main/java/androidx/recyclerview/widget/GridLayoutManager.java#552) it seems that if spanCount changes while the loop has started your error is possible. And I imagine this can happen if you have a long/slow rendering list and fast orientation changes